# How to remove non-empty directory with Node.js

Tags: node.js, directory

How to remove non empty directory in Node.js? I mean do the same as `rm -R <DIR>`. Not launching another process.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [fs-extra#remove(dir, callback)](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#removedir-callback):

> Removes a file or directory. The directory can have contents. Like rm -rf.

`fs-extra` adds additional functionality to the builtin `fs`. You can simply replace all your existing usages of `fs` by `fs-extra`.

[edit 2019] For removing directories, `fs-extra` wraps `rimraf`. So in case one only needs **this** specific functionality, including the [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) package instead is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rmdir(d) {
    var self = arguments.callee
    if (fs.existsSync(d)) {
        fs.readdirSync(d).forEach(function(file) {
            var C = d + '/' + file
            if (fs.statSync(C).isDirectory()) self(C)
            else fs.unlinkSync(C)
        })
        fs.rmdirSync(d)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode ("use strict";)